# Let's get critical: Mar 2015 Site Self-Evaluation

Tags: discussion, site-evaluation

We all love [Sustainable Living Stack Exchange](http://sustainability.stackexchange.com), but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.

The [Site Self-Evaluation review queue](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/review/site-eval) is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. 
Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.

Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? **Post an answer below to share your thoughts** and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Final Results

- [When buying beer is refilling growlers better than recycling bottles and cans?](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/4288/when-buying-beer-is-refilling-growlers-better-than-recycling-bottles-and-cans)

**Net Score: 3** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [How can I tell if the flower bulbs I buy contain neonicotinoids?](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/4333/how-can-i-tell-if-the-flower-bulbs-i-buy-contain-neonicotinoids)

**Net Score: 2** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Pool, sauna and shower with electric heating and solar thermal vs gas heating?](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/4310/pool-sauna-and-shower-with-electric-heating-and-solar-thermal-vs-gas-heating)

**Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [Solar PV panels - Worth the cost of more efficient panels?](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/4290/solar-pv-panels-worth-the-cost-of-more-efficient-panels)

**Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [What's the fastest growing plant by carbon density?](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/4315/whats-the-fastest-growing-plant-by-carbon-density)

**Net Score: -1** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 2)

---

- [How much energy costs do portable solar panels save in a house?](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/4337/how-much-energy-costs-do-portable-solar-panels-save-in-a-house)

**Net Score: -1** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [Can alloy wheels (for a car) pay for themselves through fuel savings?](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/4316/can-alloy-wheels-for-a-car-pay-for-themselves-through-fuel-savings)

**Net Score: -1** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [Are there solar concentrator builds that work without tracking?](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/4336/are-there-solar-concentrator-builds-that-work-without-tracking)

**Net Score: -1** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [Less energy consumption when we stop using fossil fuels?](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/4294/less-energy-consumption-when-we-stop-using-fossil-fuels)

**Net Score: -2** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 0, Needs Improvement: 3)

---

- [Prevent concrete roof from absorbing too much heat during summer](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/4335/prevent-concrete-roof-from-absorbing-too-much-heat-during-summer)

**Net Score: -3** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 3)

---

Answer (score 2):

As with previous evaluations, our questions rarely ranked highly on google.

Thanks to THelper for changing the title on our best evaluation question: to a British ear or eye, the question "is it worth getting beer in growlers?" means something very different to what it means in the USA, and would not be on topic here.